# Php find a specific regex

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to get a specific string in a .less file such as :

```
@underlineTitle:none;
@fondContent:#eeeeee;
@colorContent:#5D5D5D;
@fondField:#ffffff;
```

For instance I would like to get `#eeeeee`right after `@fondContent:`, until the `;`, but I can not find how. Even trying this did not work as expected :

```
preg_match('%@fondContent:(.*)%i', $source, $output);
```

**UPDATE** Below is my current output:

```
0: "@fondContent:#eeeeee;"
1: "#eeeeee;"
```

Comment: what output are you getting ?

Comment: so what is wrong ? you are getting what you wanted

Comment: I get the `;`that I do not want actually

Comment: Why voted me down? Seriously can't ask anything on this forum anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you have two choices:

- Either keep using `(.*)` and tell where to stop - so add a `;` after the group,
- or as suggested by Amal Murali in the comments here use `([^;]+)`. `[^;]+` matches any characters that are not (`^`) `;`

```
%@fondContent:(.*);%i
%@fondContent:([^;]+)%i
```

Comment: Actually `(.*)` will work fine, because `.` does not match newlines.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ok, but is it guaranteed that there is only one statement per line? (in OP's example it is, I know)

Comment: lazy or greedy wont matter here, its not needed

Comment: @aelor Ok, rephrased my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
%(?<=@fondContent:)(#[a-z\d]+)%i
```

The above looks behind for `@fondContent:` and then matches (and captures) `#` + alphabet-or-digit characters.

Comment: I'm not sure if using `\w` is a good idea. "*The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if **locale-specific** matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.*" — [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Answer (score 1):

`%@fondContent:(.*);%i` put that semicolon at the end so that it will not come inside the capture group

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: `\@fondContent:\s?#([abcdefABCDEF0-9]{6}|[abcdefABCDEF0-9]{3});`

Validates real colors (a-f 0-9)

```
\@fondContent:\s?#([abcdefABCDEF0-9]{6}|[abcdefABCDEF0-9]{3});
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YOtyJBcXQkq5J31l)

```
@fondContent: #Ef3dee; // valide
@fondContent:#Ef3dee; // valide
@fondContent: #ZZ3dee; // not valide
@fondContent: #Ef3deee; // not valide
@fondContent: #Ef3; // valide
```

Comment: Why isn't `#eee` valid?

Comment: Because I added specific `{6}`. So it needs to be 6 chars long. You could change this to `{3,6}` but it validate all between 3 to 6 chars.

Comment: I know why it wouldn't match, I was asking why it *shouldn't*. `#eee` is valid.